# TOEFL reading book

Tags: american-english

I want to ask you if you know any TOEFL book which has passage for TOEFL reading sections, just passages, I mean book maybe with millions pages but just passages.

Comment: Smolina, yes this is OT here, but we have a meta site where, I think, you surely can ask for these kind of questions. Moreover, we have a chat where you can find some expert users who might help you.

Comment: what is meta? also how could i chat here? thank u very much

Comment: Smolina, see [http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) and at the bottom of this page you can see a link named 'chat' (I use the mobile version of this site).

Comment: Just to make clear what @Carlo_R. said: On the meta site, you can ask if a question is OT on this very site. The meta site is not the site where to ask questions about TOEFL books, or other questions about resources.

Comment: I am reading Longman prepration course for the Toefl IBT
it has skills with good passages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written TOEFL before and from my experience Reading Comprehension part is the easiest one. There is no need to buy a book with billion pages. Just buy a book of TOEFL and read the RC part. Writing and speaking are the most difficult sections.

Comment: which book do you advice? what is the hardest section?

Comment: There are tons of books available, Check out Amazon. BTW I wrote TOEFL without any preparation so dont know any names. I got 27 in RC and 14 in writing.

Comment: i am afraid of this test, i have 2 month to prepare do u think it is enough time? i am not very good at english

Comment: Well that is what it is about, to check your english. Buy one book of toefl and see the pattern and give the tests. Speaking is something you are gonna have to do it on your own, and I believe that is the most challenging if you are not good at it.